# Incorrect Output for varchar(32) in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-query-store, isqlquery

I have some `varchar(32)` field in my `ERP` database in item Master, but when I want to get these field in SQL query it gives incorrect output for example `6M - 6`. Please any suggestions to solve the issue and get the correct output.

```
Select [No_], [Description], [Expiration Calculation], [Shelf Life], [Near Expiry Calc_]
FROM [Dr_Morepen Limited$Item] AS ITEM
```

Actual Data in Database

```
No_         Description        Expiration Calculation   Shelf Life  Near Expiry Calc_
GBP00368    BURNOL - 10GM TUBE  6M                       24M         6M
GBP00369    BURNOL - 20 GM TUBE 6M                       24M         6M
```

Output In SQL

```
No_         Description         Expiration Calculation  Shelf Life  Near Expiry Calc_
GBP00368    BURNOL - 10GM TUBE  6                       24          6
GBP00369    BURNOL - 20 GM TUBE 6                       24          6
```

Please Help.

Comment: can you show the schema for the table and format a little better? what specific field is not returning correctly?

Comment: Maybe confine your example to only the field(s) which have/has a problem?

Comment: "Actual data in database".  How do you know that?  When you select the value, it looks different.  I don't think the data is what you think it is.